# Get nested record on page

Tags: xslt, umbraco, umbraco-contour

Im new with XML and XSLT and wonder if any one can help here:

I have an XML form with the below data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<uformrecords> 
  <uformrecord> 
    <state>Approved</state> 
    <created>2009-11-13T10:01:55</created> 
    <updated>2009-11-13T10:01:55</updated> 
    <id>119ecc43-df79-46e1-9020-b2e27e239175</id> 
    <ip>127.0.0.1</ip> 
    <pageid>0</pageid> 
    <memberkey></memberkey> 
    <fields> 
      <name record="119ecc43-df79-46e1-9020-b2e27e239175" sortorder="0"> 
        <key>2295187e-0345-4260-a406-eabcc1e774e2</key> 
        <fieldKey>e6157c93-0b54-4415-b7ba-5c7c2c953b70</fieldKey> 
        <caption>Name</caption> 
        <datatype>String</datatype> 
        <values> 
          <value><![CDATA[My Name]]></value>
        </values>
      </name>
      <email record="119ecc43-df79-46e1-9020-b2e27e239175" sortorder="1"> 
        <key>a92875a8-938d-4ba0-990a-59a3518ce62c</key> 
        <fieldKey>d8b10ffb-c437-4a44-8df6-01e6af5ac26f</fieldKey> 
        <caption>Email</caption> 
        <datatype>String</datatype> 
        <values> 
          <value><![CDATA[pph@testdomain.com]]></value> 
        </values> 
      </email> 
    </fields>
  </uformrecord>
</uformrecords>
```

On the page i have the below XSLT code in order to get some records

```
<ul> <xsl:for-each select="umbraco.contour:GetRecordsFromPage($currentPage/@id)//uformrecord"> 
    <xsl:sort select="created" order="ascending"/> 
    <li> 
        A record with id id <xsl:value-of select="id"/> with the state set to <xsl:value-of select="state"/> i 
        was created on <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:LongDate(created)"/> 
    </li> 

    </xsl:for-each> 
</ul>
```

This works fine but if i add caption

```
<xsl:value-of select="caption"/>
```

the field is empty. I think its empty as the node may need to be iterated through. So i have the below code to iterate through the records

```
<xsl:for-each select="umbraco.contour:GetRecord($id)/uformrecord/fields/child::*"> 
    <xsl:sort select="caption" order="ascending"/> 
    <h4> 
        <xsl:value-of select=" caption"/> 
    </h4> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

but i have the error that ID is not declared - if i declare id i get the error that its not in the proper GUID format. Could anyone advise how to get over this problem and show the "caption" element?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first **xsl:for-each** you are iterating over **uformrecord**, so that will be your context within the loop.

```
<xsl:for-each select="umbraco.contour:GetRecordsFromPage($currentPage/@id)//uformrecord">
```

However, as you spotted, the **caption** element is not an immediate child of the **uformrecord** element, but is lower down under **field** elements.

As you are already positioned on an **uformrecord**, you should be able to simplify your **xsl:for-each** to this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="fields/*"> 
    <xsl:sort select="caption" order="ascending"/> 
    <h4> 
        <xsl:value-of select="caption"/> 
    </h4> 
</xsl:for-each>
```